# Compressing list in prolog using Member and Append

Tags: prolog

I'm currently learning prolog and doing the 99 prolog excersises thing.
I've got a question to compress a list, such that all duplicate elements should be removed.

Desired outcome:

```
?- compress([a,a,a,a,b,c,c,a,a,d,e,e,e,e],X).
X = [a,b,c,d,e]
```

My code currently looks like:

```
compress([],[]).
compress([H|T], X) :- 
    (  \+ member(H, X) -> 
       append([H],X,X)
    ), compress(T,X).
```

By running this with `trace` it always fails in after the first append, and returns false.
Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`append([H],X,X)` - this line is nonsense. If `X` is a finite list, you cannot prepend a non-empty list to it and still get the same list `X`.

Prolog programs are statements of fact and deduction rules, like a mathematical proof, not imperatives like `x = [h] + x`. There are no "variables" in the same sense as in Java/C++/JavaScript programs.

In particular, `compress([H|T], X) :- foo, compress(T,X).` also looks weird, because you say that the result of compressing list `[H|T]` (namely, `X`) is the same as the result of compressing list `T` (`X` as well), but only if `foo` is correct.

Also, if you want to get `[a,b]` for `[a,b,a]`, then you probably have to add extra predicates. Predicate cannot "remember" anything (e.g. it cannot "iterate over all items and only get the first occurrence). It can only make recursive calls.

If you're ok with keeping the last occurrence only, I'd write it the following way:

```
compress([],[]).  % Empty list
compress([H|T], X) :-
  member(H, T),    % If H is not the last occurrence...
  compress(T, X).  % remove duplicates from the tail, ignore H.
compress([H|T], X) :-
  not(member(H, T)),  % If H is the last occurrence...
  compress(T, XT),    % ...compress the tail...
  append([H], XT, X). % ...and prepend H to the result.
```

Comment: `append([H], XT, X)` is the same as simpler/cheaper `X = [H|XT]` and you should prefer ISO `\+` to non-ISO old-school `not/1` but otherwise, fine answer!

Comment: Also, it may be preferable to use `memberchk/2` instead of `member/2` if you aren't interested in obtaining the solutions but rather just checking for something being in a list or not.